# один сканер для двух переменных String и int

Tags: java, строки, intellij-idea, указатели

Есть проблема, Пользователь в данной игре должен выбрать на что он ставит, на цвет на четность или же на конкретное число, но проблема в том что сканер считывает только переменные типа `String` то есть принимает ставки только на цвет и четность, а надо сделать так что бы сканер мог считывать как и `String` так и `int`, в зависимости от того на что поставит пользователь

```
System.out.println("Сделайте вашу ставку. Вы можете поставить на Красное или 
Черное, на Четное или Нечетное или на конкретное число.");
        stavka = scanner.next();
```

Comment: И что вам мешает попробовать распарсить строку?

Answer (score 1):

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  String s = scanner.nextLine();
  try
  {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("переменная типа int " + a);
  } catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("переменная типа String " + s);
  }

  System.out.println(s);
```

Как то так.

Comment: Не работает.(((

Comment: Exception? что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Не инициализирует потом переменные

Comment: @Roman Область видимости у переменной какая? Не тем вы занимаетесь 4й день. Если бы прочли мат часть знали бы, что переменная доступна только в том блоке в котором она объявлена. То есть за пределами блока `try` переменная `a` недоступна. Вам уже писали в прошлых вопросах что у вас проблемы с областью видимости. Почему вы не удосужились разобраться?

Comment: А, их нужно проинициализировать и присвоить дефолтные значения перед блоком try{} catch . А уже в блоке парсить.